# Maven assembly plugin: how to include provided dependencies of transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

It seems that including direct dependencies with `provided` scope is well understood.  It also appears that including transitive dependencies with `runtime` scope is also easily accomplished.

But how can I include a dependency two levels of indirection away?

Example:

```
A --> B --> C
```

Where A depends on B (compile scope) and B depends on C (provided scope).

I want `A` to retrieve `C` (eg: download the jar locally), be it via assembly descriptor or `maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies` or some other mechanism.

I've tried seemingly every combination of options for both of the aforementioned plugins.  Neither approach covers this scenario.  They both get `B` (even if `B` is changed to a provided dependency), and any compile scope dependencies of `B`, but not provided dependencies of B.

I suppose that I'm trying to do something similar to a shaded representation of my project but without unpacking dependencies.

Naturally I don't want to have to enumerate all of B's dependencies in A's pom - I'd like to retrieve (and then package) all dependencies implicitly and recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that. It is not a limitation of the `maven-assembly-plugin`, but the way Maven considers transitive dependencies. A transitive dependency that is of scope `provided` will be omitted, always (refer to [this table](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) in the documentation).

There is an open bug about this ([MNG-2205](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2205)) but I don't think it will be fixed anytime soon. This really is intended behaviour because `provided` dependencies, as per the name, as supposed to be provided at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Although Tunaki is quite right, I found a workable solution that's better than nothing, using a less well-known plugin (NOTE: only works with Maven <= 3.0.X)

This specifies two dependency blocks. The first pulls in normal compile deps including transitive, it's the same as using copy-dependencies.  The second block specifically mentions B in addition to the normal pom dependency declaration (unfortunately, but at least both dependency mentions are in the same pom) and requests its provided deps:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
            <artifactId>copy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-provided-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/lib</targetPath>
                                <dependencies>
                                    <dependency>
                                        <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                                    </dependency>
                                    <dependency>
                                        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>artifact_i_call_B</artifactId>
                                        <version>1.0</version>
                                        <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
                                    </dependency>
                                </dependencies>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Docs for this plugin may only exist in the archive at this point, not sure what happened to it:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130826193436/http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin